# How do I match the last occurrence of a complex repeating pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

**NOTE**
The accepted answer from @Toto ultimately works better in the real world on a large file with many possible matches, however, if you're using a similar regex on a file of any size, with only a few possible matches, then @Pavel Lint's answer will be fine and possibly be faster, though I haven't tested the speed. Keep in mind that the differences here are in milliseconds, so not much in reality unless you are doing this a large number of times in a row.

---

I have the following string, which is from part of a SQL Error Log file (modified for clarity):

2020-01-27 11:12:00.72 Backup      Log was backed up. Database: ReportServerTempDB, creation date(time): 2019/05/22(12:31:06), first LSN: 79:1911:1, last LSN: 79:1933:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'E:\SQLLogDumps\ReportServerTempDB_tlog_20200127111200.trn'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
**2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.

2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Occurrence number one**
2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: 192.168.4.208]
**2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.

2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Occurrence number two**
2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
2020-01-27 11:21:47.95 Logon       Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: 192.168.4.208]

The text in bold above is what is being matched by the expression I've written thus far.
I want to find the **last** occurrence of a line containing "Severity: 20" plus the following line, aka the second of the bold sections. However, in the wild there could be any number of occurrences in one document.

I've played around on regex101.com, and read a lot of the content at [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), but can't make a regex that works.

The current expression I have is:
`^.*Severity: 20.*\R^.*(?!(^.*\R)*Severity: 20)`

I've also done a lot of poking around on Google but can't find anything that helps for matching repeating patterns that span mulitple lines and are part of a long document.

*Is it possible to match only the last occurrence of the pattern? If so, how?*

To clarify, I'm looking for pure regex. I know this is possible in Python by returning all matches as a list, then get the last element of the list, but I don't have that option. Also, I'm using the Notepad++ regex search, which I believe uses the *Boost* version of regex.

---

**UPDATE**

Both of the given answers work perfectly on the test string, however the results are very interesting on a large/real file, see below for more details.

Based on the test string above, I've benchmarked the answers from @Pavel Lint and @Toto. @Pavel Lint's answer is quite a bit faster, by a factor of roughly 10 in terms of milliseconds.

@Pavel Lint
`^.+Severity: 20.*\R^.*\R(?![\s\S]*Severity: 20)`
1588 steps, average of 2ms

@Toto
`[\s\S]+\K^.*?Severity: 20.*\R.*`
61955 steps, average of 36ms

**However**, the results are very different on a real file. Now, I can't provide the actual file I've used for testing as it is a client's log file, so I don't fault @Pavel Lint for the answer, as it works perfectly fine on the test string. I possibly wasn't clear enough in my question about what this would need to work on in the wild, however I did state that "in the wild there could be **any** number of occurrences in one document", which I believe covers scenarios where we want to avoid catastrophic backtracking.

The test file has 26,192 lines, and 1595 occurrences of a 'Severity: 20' error (matching the pattern shown in the test string, however the message in the second line will be different and could include any word/number/special characters).

The first regex above, from @Pavel Lint, killed Notepad++ when I ran it.
My semi-educated guess is that catastrophic backtracking occurred.

The second regex, from @Toto, matched the last occurrence almost instantly.

Ultimately, @Toto's answer is slower for small samples but scales to very large files with many possible matches.

Comment: On notepad++ you can simply change the direction of search to "up" and then do a search for the next result, starting at the end. Whatever the search catches will be the last match.

Comment: I've just had a look and choosing the 'regex' option limits the search direction to down. Yes, I know I could look for something simple like "Severity: 20" and not use regex, but if possible I would like to use regex.

Comment: What version are you using? I'm on v7.7.1 and can search backwards just fine

Comment: Ah I see, I'm on 7.3.3, due to other reasons (using the "Python Script" plugin). I assume it was added later.

Comment: If you can't upgrade, then you're out of luck. Regex has no concept of "first" or "last". An alternative would be to use "Find All in Current Document" and then click on the last line on the window that shows up. Or you could search for `.+<rest of the pattern>` with "`.` matches newline" turned on, and the end of the match will be the line you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware regex has no concept of first/last, but it does have the concept of 'this' not followed by 'that'.. ie negative-lookahead, which can be used as a way of finding the last occurrence of a pattern that matches multiple times. Using the term 'last' communicates what I'm looking for much more clearly in a few words.

Comment: I think Toto's code is slower because of `[\s\S]+\K` , if you remove it from his given code,  it will work much faster,  , for my editor `\R` doesn't work so I usually use `\n` instead ... as `^.*?Severity: 20.*\n.*\n?` , it's very quick .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `[\s\S]+\K^.*?Severity: 20.*\R.*`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[\s\S]+             # 1 or more any character
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
^                   # beginning of line
  .*?               # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  Severity: 20      # literally
  .*                # 0 or more any character but newline
  \R                # any kind of linebreak
  .*                # 0 or more any character but newline
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: I can follow this, but I don't understand how it works without a negative-lookahead..? I assume it's related to the ```\K```?

Comment: @Jlanger: `\K` acts like a variable-length lookbehind. It works because of `[\s\S]+` that matches any character greedily until the last line that contains `Severity: 20` `\K` removes from the match everything encountered before this line

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I can't test it right now, but I'm guessing this would be faster than anything involving a negative-lookahead? As it doesn't involve backtracking... The reason I ask is that a SQL error log file could have 10k+ lines with thousands of Severity 20 errors, in which case I'm fairly sure that backtracking would kill the regex (catastrophic backtracking?)

Comment: @Jlanger: I haven't done benchmark but I think it will be faster.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow when I'm at work. Your answer is simpler and may be faster, but I'd like to confirm so I can update the question with any further related info (as to speed), then I'll accept. Feel free to benchmark it if you want to, my way will be to see how many steps each one takes, if you have a better way then let me know 

Comment: Tested it, interestingly, @Pavel Lint answer is a lot faster, even though it involves a negative look-ahead. Would you know why that is?

Comment: I've now tested both answers on a real file, with interesting results. See my update.

Comment: @Jlanger: Interesting that file size causes such difference.

Comment: I think it's mainly the fact that in my test file there are 1500+ other matches, so using a negative-lookahead would cause a lot of back-and-forth scanning as it finds each match. After removing all of the matches apart from the last one, Pavel Lint's regex worked fine. I still don't fully understand the massive difference on benchmarking the test string though. 61955 steps for that little string seems a lot, though it is still practically instantaneous. And what I REALLY don't understand, is how your answer is STILL almost instant on a file ~3000 times larger linewise!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to achieve what you want with this regex:

```
^.+Severity: 20.*\R^.*\R(?![\s\S]*Severity: 20)
```

It's pretty much the same idea that you put there initially, but in the negative lookahead block I replaced `.*` with `[\s\S]*` so that it works for newlines.

Here's the demo: https://regex101.com/r/XWWFYc/1/

Comment: So I've benchmarked the answers, and yours is quite a bit faster, even though it involves a negative-lookahead, which I expected would be slower. Do you know why this is the case? (In the interest of myself/others learning why)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it will still prove very useful for others looking for this information.